# How to get filtered dependency graph only for certain library

Tags: android-studio, gradle, dependencies

I am searching for uses of a certain library, with

```
 ./gradlew :app:dependencies > output_file.txt
```

and it is a very long file. and Is there any command that will only show me with compose as the library?

Comment: try `gradle -q dependencyInsight --dependency abc --configuration xyz` see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/viewing_debugging_dependencies.html#sec:identifying_reason_dependency_selection

Comment: @PrasadU how can i do this in Android studio